# Press/simulate keyboard keys in access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am automating a process in my office, and saving a pdf file is part of it. So how can I save it? I need to press ***Ctr+Shift+s*** ..
I see solutions here but its in java. Looking for anyone who can share ways on how to simulate this. Also tried `SendKeys` but I can't pull Ctr and Shift.

`SendKeys "S"`

`SendKeys "{TAB}"`

- this types "S", tab, well its tabs to the next control. But {CONTROL} , {SHIFT} does not work.

Is this possible? Or are there other ways to do this?

Comment: Only tried sendkeys, which I think is for excel, but I still did, and I cant use control and shift. updated my question above

Comment: Why are you using sendkeys? If the goal is to simply save a report as a pdf there are better ways to do this. What are you trying to do specifically?

Comment: I use access vba to automate our process in IE, I need to save a PDF preview > then name it to something else. `SendKeys` works now by setting focus to the pdf preview in IE, then hitting ctrl shift S. another sendkeys for the file name. Is there any other better way? This is what I found after googling. But maybe you have something better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keyboard modifiers have a special syntax, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/sendkeys-statement).

Ctrl + Shift + s = `SendKeys "^+s"`

Comment: I was looking for this the whole day, why haven't I gone through this? Thanks!